# Fetching data from Database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to fetch data from database table named 'users' and display the output in a table.

I have written below code but it's not working.

I am using Laravel 5.5

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')

<div class="container">

<h2>Admin Panel</h2>

<p>Data of the Registered Users.</p> 

<table class="table table-bordered">

<thead>

<tr>

<th>Id</th>

<th>Name</th>

<th>Email</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

$users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();

@foreach($users as $value)

<tr>

<td>{{ $value->id }}</td>

<td>{{ $value->name }}</td>

<td>{{ $value->email }}</td>

</tr>

@endforeach

</tbody>

</table>

</div>


@endsection
```

> Error: Undefined Variable: users

Comment: Post your `view` and `controller` code where you send `users` to the view and how you `loop` over them

Comment: I have written anything else, other than this

Comment: sorry "haven't"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to mix PHP within your (Blade) template. Although it is possible to do so with `@php` directives, this is bad practice: your view should not contain any business logic.

Ideally you want to pass this data from your controller. It should look something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();

        return view('some-view')->with('users', $users);
    }
}
```

Read more on passing data to views [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views).

Comment: How can I make this page to update data automatically?

Comment: @user9332352 That's a whole different issue that justifies another question. But do some research first. Consider polling, websockets, pub/sub...

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it all wrong, the point of `MVC` design is to have your `controllers` do the application logic, your views to represent a `representation of that data` and models to `contain the data you need`, in your case you are missing the point completely by using `DB::table` inside of your view, so here is an example code which you **might need to correct a bit**:

**The example below doesn't show `MVC` pattern since the `data` is passed from inside a closure of a `route`**

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();
    return view('VIEW-NAME-HERE', compact('users'));
});
```

**view.blade.php**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{ $user->id }} {{ $user->name }} {{ $user->email }}
@endforeach
```

Change `VIEW-NAME-HERE` with the name of your `view` file, for example `index` or `users.index`

Answer (score 0):

You Are using php in blade file
first make controller
for controller run a command in terminal
php artisan make:controller usercontroller

then write this:

```
class usercontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();

        $data = compact('users')
        return view('your-view-name')->with('$data');
    }
}
```